# Setting up Windows 10 virtual machine in Fedora

Tags: fedora, windows, virtual-machine, qemu

I recently made a total shift to Linux(Fedora 32). Ran dual boot with Win 10 for a month and then removed Windows from dual boot.

However, MS Office is being taught in my sister's school. So, I need to be able to run MS Office for her to practice. After googling around for Wine install vs virtual machine, I decided to go with installing a Windows 10 virtual machine on QEMU(virt-manager). Can someone please help with these concerns?

1. Is this a good idea on a PC with 8 GB RAM?
2. I was thinking of creating a new user account and removing all non-essential softwares from that account so that the load on RAM decreases. How should I go about doing that?

Comment: Sorry this isn't an answer to your specific question, but I also need Windows 10 for some school work.  I installed it in a VirtualBox VM and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

8GB of RAM to share between the host & guest is going to be pushing it. I run a similar setup with 16GB RAM; 8GB for Windows 10 works for me.

Now, if it's just for practicing MS Office, why not use Office 365 on-line? The interface is nearly identical and you won't have to use a VM at all.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you're going to run a 32bit Windows 10 instance it might be enough in case you allocate 3GB or **less** RAM to your VM. Generally 8GB of RAM is too little to virtualize a heavy operating system like Windows 10. I'd say 12GB is a bare minimum.
2. Background Fedora Linux services barely make a dent in RAM usage. The most memory hungry app nowadays on desktop Linux might be your desktop environment itself, e.g. Gnome or KDE (both can easily grab over 1GB of RAM; XFCE is a lot more frugal; IceWM barely consumes any resources), your web browser and Electron/Chrome based apps.